# Circle Image View with Text

Tags: android, image, view, geometry

anyone got an idea how to make something like this?

[image]

I've tried solution found here [Android how to create view like this in Circular shape having imageview and text view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978212/android-how-to-create-view-like-this-in-circular-shape-having-imageview-and-text)

Tried to play around with de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView but still cant find any solution.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-a-circular-image-view-in-android

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners

Comment: it's not duplicate his question is slightly differrent

Comment: Show us what have you tried, what didn't work. from my experience, library that you mentioned works just fine.

Comment: it sure works in making the circle image view. but what i cant get is the text part. how do u create the half bottom circle text view?

Comment: @YohHendry Check this https://github.com/VizGhar/Android-CircularView/tree/develop Give your feedback