# create customise button with image at top and text at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

i am referrring this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978212/android-how-to-create-view-like-this-in-circular-shape-having-imageview-and-text) , but it dosent help

[image: Expected result][image: Output result]

**Source code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="collection"
            type="com.techryde.bajafresh.data.model.local.CollectionDb" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whitecircle">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/circle_layoutinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rating_viewtv"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_inset_drawable">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/country_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:url="@{collection.imageUrl}" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating_viewtv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:text="@{collection.collectionName}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**whitecircle.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

</shape>
```

**circletwo.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <!--<solid android:color="#ff9546" />-->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

**circle_insert_drawable.xml**

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circletwo"
    android:insetTop="40dp"
    android:visible="true" />
```

Cant figure out whats the issue is? If anyone has face this issue before it would be great of ur help .Thanks

Comment: try using cardviews

Comment: have used cardview also. but is also not helping out. if you can provide some example it would be great.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can easily create button with drawable top...

```
<Button android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_Content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/yourimage"
    android:background="your circle shap drawble"/>
```

Comment: that dosent help. i want the text in bottom as shown and image in above section as shown.

Comment: @AnkitOstwal drawble top will put a image on Top

Comment: how will you show red color bg behind text & that too in a effect as shown in image, at the bottom?

Comment: you can put color in circle shape drawble

Comment: i am getting output like this.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghxh3hmcjauiz6m/Screen%20Shot%202016-12-30%20at%203.14.52%20pm.png?dl=0  .. But i want as shown in question above.

Comment: use larger image or mix this image with a larger image with white background

Comment: that dosent help. images comes from server. If you can figure out above code , and help me out that would be great.Thanks

Comment: then use cardviews

Comment: should i use background as circle drawable in cardview

Comment: can you provide some hint @AbhishekSingh

Comment: ya waiting & i am trying to implement same as directed by you.Thanks

Comment: i am not able to make circular card.